# How to divide the data(Reference ids) from 1 txt file to 5 txt files ,data should be different in each file

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a jmeter script for a travel web application which generates booking reference ids in a txt file.My requirement is to feed that txt file. as a data file to other script.But i need 5 text files of booking reference ids with no same booking reference ids in each file.

For example:
There is a file Bookingref.txt which has all booking ids

In another script,i want to make use of above bookings for making amendments.There are 5 amendments i have to make ,so i need file files with booking reference ids but all the 5 files should have different booking ids

Solution i tried but didnt work out:
I took the count of booking reference ids generated in Bookingref.txt and divided the count by 5 and tried to put for loop to put equal no of data to all 5 files.I got stuck and figured it wont work .

```
BookingCount=vars.get("bookingref_matchNr");
Count=Bookingcount/5;
int rounded_count=(int)Math.round(Count);
for(i=1;i<=rounded_count;i++)
{
write to 1 text file
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files are myfile1.txt, myfile2.txt,..
You can add value to files inside `for` loop:

```
new File('myfile' + i + '.txt') << BookingCount
```